# finding pdf of y given piecewise pdf of x

Tags: statistics

if the pdf of x is $f_x(x)=\frac{1}{2}$ for $0\leq x \leq 1$ and $\frac{1}{2x^2}$ for $1\leq x \leq \infty$ and $Y=\frac{1}{x}$

what is the pdf of y.

The supports aren't the same so I am having trouble using the monotone piecewise transform.
I have tried another way where $f_y(y)=\frac{d}{dy}P(Y\leq y)=\frac{d}{dy}P(\frac{1}{X}\leq y)=\frac{d}{dy}P(X\geq \frac{1}{y})=\frac{d}{dy}(1-P(X\leq \frac{1}{y}))$ giving me $1-\frac{y^2}{2}$ for $0\leq y \leq \frac{1}{2}$ but the pdf wont integrate to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{d}{dy}(1-P(X\leq \frac{1}{y}))=-\frac{d}{dy}P(X\leq \frac{1}{y})=-f_X(1/y)*\frac{d}{dy}(1/y)=\frac{f_X(1/y)}{y^2}$. Now consider $y<1$ and $y>1$.

In general, if $Y=g(X)$ for one to one $g$ $$f_Y(y)=\frac{f_X(g^{-1}(y))}{|g'(g^{-1}(y))|}$$

Comment: So you would get $ f_y(y)=\frac{1}{2y^2}$ for $\? \leq y \leq \? $ or $ f_y(y)=\frac{1}{2}$ for $0 \leq y \leq 1$ y never gets bigger than 1 in the pdf of x.

Comment: So you would get $ f_y(y)=\frac{1}{2y^2}$ for $1 \leq y \leq \infty $ or $ f_y(y)=\frac{1}{2}$ for $0 \leq y \leq 1$  which is the exact same pdf as x which seems odd